# Using Consolibyte Quickbooks Web Connector, how can I keep two sets of books separate?

Tags: quickbooks

I have a client that has two separate Quickbooks Company Files (books) on the same Quickbooks installation. One is for one type of client (type A) and the other for another (type B).

I have created two separate web connector apps for these two books (except the url to the soap service is the same) and installed them with the appropriate book open.

However, when I do an import, the records imported (customers, items), are for whichever set of books is open at the time. Thus, despite having a separate web connector username and password for each set of books, it's importing 'type B' customers as 'type A' and vise versa. That is, the username associated with 'type A' records is sometimes the username for 'type B' customers.

I have the same issue with importing Items from Quickbooks.

How can I keep these two sets of books separate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Web Connector calls an `authenticate` SOAP method, and the response from that method can contain the file path of the correct QuickBooks file to connect to.

The SOAP method looks like this:

```
array authenticate(string strUserName, string strPassword)
```

And the array you return should look like this:

```
array(
  'a valid ticket string goes here',   // send the session ID/ticket here
  'C:/path/to/your/company/file.QBW'  // you can send *either* an empty string to use the currently open QuickBooks company file, or specify a specific company file to use by sending the full path to that company file
)
```

The 2nd array value is optional, *but* you can use it to lock each user down to a particular `.QBW` file/set of books like you're asking.

Here's a raw HTTP response for your reference:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 02 May 2009 17:43:09 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.9 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.9 OpenSSL/0.9.7l DAV/2 PHP/5.2.9
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.9
Content-Length: 387
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://developer.intuit.com/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns1:authenticateResponse>
            <ns1:authenticateResult>
                <ns1:string></ns1:string>
                <ns1:string>C:\path\to\your\books.QBW</ns1:string>
            </ns1:authenticateResult>
        </ns1:authenticateResponse>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Ref: http://wiki.consolibyte.com/wiki/doku.php/quickbooks_web_connector#array_authenticate_string_strusername_string_strpassword

Comment: Looks like the easiest way to accomplish this is to add the Company File path to the users table. (quickbooks_user.qb_company_file)